# T-SQL stored procs orders of magnitude faster than LINQ

Tags: sql, linq

According to answers I've seen on stackoverflow, stored procedures (and to a lesser extent db functions) tend to perform better vs. LINQ + ORM frameworks (e.g. Entity Framework).

I want to determine if the performance difference is large enough to justify an increase in development time, assuming it takes more time to write equivalent, reasonably complex query operations in T-SQL vs. LINQ.

In which scenarios is there an order-of-magnitude (or at least a very large constant factor) difference in running time, between a performance-optimized stored proc  and its equivalent, performance-optimized LINQ counterpart? Or for scalar- or table- valued functions vs. the LINQ equivalent?

Hopefully, it is not too difficult to see that this question follows the guidelines per the [FAQ](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq). It's not asking a subjective question like, "which is better, T-SQL or LINQ?". It's asking for a few specific scenarios  (can give abstract or concrete examples)  where there is a significant difference in performance. If that still doesn't make sense to you, and you still think this question is not constructive and should be closed, please leave an explanation why if you can.

Comment: Every LINQ provider is different and will produce different SQL, so you really cannot generalize.  Furthermore, "reasonably complex query operations" will often be impractical, if not impossible, to translate into LINQ - and more often then not, if it is even possible, it will be considerably more time consuming than just writing the SQL in the first place.

Comment: @qes: A good comment, but I doubt this. Cannot generalize? Is the generated T-SQL or the algorithms used to generate it from e.g. LINQ-to-SQL and Entity Framework, really so fundamentally  different? By time-consuming here I assume you mean  development time, not running time (i.e. the question)? Even still, not necessarily. For example, suppose your query involved concatenation, other string manipulation, iteration,with persistence of some state from one row to the next, and calls to trigonometry functions...

Comment: You doubt it?  How many LINQ providers have you worked with?  L2S and EF are only 2 of dozens, and both from Microsoft at that.  The algorithms used *are* quite different (even from L2S to EF, heck even from one version of EF to the next) for anything but the simplest single table select statements - and those are of no interest to your question it would seem.  It will be considerably more time consuming, yes, in development time - as you fight to make a complex SQL statement simply translate from LINQ at all.  Even reasonably simple joins in SQL can be tricky or even impossible

Comment: It seems you don't really understand how short most LINQ providers fall.  String manipulation?  Maybe 50/50 chance it's implemented. Iteration with persistence of state?  Calling trig functions?  Not happening.  Use L2S, EF, SubSonic, LLBLGen, Lightspeed, etc. - at least a handful - and see what you find for yourself.  And that's not even getting into using different LINQ providers against DB engines other than Microsoft SQL Server, another whole can of worms there.

Comment: @qes: Yes I do. More than 2, but not dozens, and I've written 2. Which are the dozens you've worked with? It seems that simplest table selects cannot be that different across different providers (and besides contradicting "cannot generalize"), how differently can a stored proc represent a simple select than LINQ to SQL can generate the equivalent T-SQL? The LINQ-to-T-SQL translators are already provided by the ORM framework, so where's the fight?

Comment: @qes: Trig functions not happening? How about financial functions? I definitely see those commonly in stored procs. Iteration w/ state not happening? FETCH. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180152.aspx
String manipulation? Last time I checked LINQ to SQL, the String functions were supported. Besides that, string, regex functions  that show up in the SELECT statement are easily applied *after* the call to IQueryProvider.Execute.
http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/65810/19936

Comment: Trig & financial - Used in stored procs.  Not in LINQ.  So if your sproc uses them, you won't be easily translating them into a LINQ query. String functions, like I said - maybe 50/50.  Some are supported, some providers are better than others (try your string functions in SubSonic and see how many work).  My point is that the type of SQL you are asking about - "reasonably complex query operations" - are more often than not, not going to be possible to simply write in LINQ - and even when you can accomplish it - runtime performance is irrelevant since development time will be lengthened.

Comment: Just look, for example, at how much cumulative time has been wasted (number of questions, for example) figuring out how to do joins (other than INNER) in LINQ.  And joins are another example of simple SQL operations that are not even broadly supported outside of L2S & EF.  Did the 2 LINQ providers you claim to have written support LEFT JOIN or Regex or financial functions?

Comment: @qes I'm aware of limitations of LINQ, e.g. the following throws an exception in LINQ2SQL VS2010, even though the second part of the BinaryExpression shouldn't need to be evaluated: 
int? version = null;
var books = db.Textbooks.Where(b => version == null || b.Version == (int)version);
Trig and financial functions don't seem to be of them. e.g. where is the issue in running the following?
var courses = db.Courses.Where(c => Math.Sin(c.Credits) != 1).ToArray();
Most financial (and trig) functions seem to require scalar parameters anyway, not rowsets.

Comment: But those JOIN questions (lol) aren't mine. One of the LINQ providers I wrote does support JOINs. http://stackoverflow.com/a/6350766/266457. And for any functions which don't have a direct T-SQL translation, the Expression tree can still be evaluated as much as possible, and let the remainder of the Expression tree be evaluated in .NET - besides the fact that the query could otherwise be immediately executed, and then run the Regex/financial functions w/ LINQ to objects afterwards.

Comment: "runtime performance is irrelevant"? but tell that to the users or developers who spend their time on performance-tuning.
Judging by the extended comments yet no answer to the actual question, it seems that either the answer is none or that you don't know?

Comment: Your question, as is, is too ill-defined to be reasonably answered.  That's what I'm saying.  In context, runtime performance is irrelevant because your assumption is most likely wrong. "I want to determine if the performance difference is large enough to justify an increase in development time, assuming it takes more time to write equivalent, reasonably complex query operations in T-SQL vs. LINQ." There isn't going to be an increase in development time to write it in T-SQL - it will be quicker than LINQ, and in many cases with complex queries it won't even be possible to write it in LINQ.

Comment: Taking it personally?  Douche.

Answer (score 9):

My suggestion:
1. Do development with LINQ to get a product to market faster.
2. Optimize performance of the whole system by using cache and alike.
3. Optimize performance of those few queries where it really matters.

In the order listed.

Comment: This answer hits the nail on the head!

Comment: But do stored procedures for much complex queries!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are making an incorrect assumption that it will take longer to create a stored procedure than an equivalent LINQ query. The extra speed can be a huge benefit though [here](http://www.peer1.com/hosting/how-slow-websites-impact-visitors-and-sales.php) is an article talking about studies by Google and Amazon where load time increases of less than .5 secs had huge impacts on revenue. Given the long life of most applications it seems foolish to worry about an extra few hours of developer time for what could work out to days of time not wasted by users and/or significant increases to revenue. Another thing to consider is MS is dropping L2S in favor of EF.

Comment: amen. forget the single developer, think of the experience for the thousands of users. The dev gets paid to write the code, the poor users end up paying as that dev makes his life easier.

Answer (score 1):

> In which scenarios is there an order-of-magnitude (or at least a very large constant factor) difference in running time, between a performance-optimized stored proc and its equivalent, performance-optimized LINQ counterpart? Or for scalar- or table- valued functions vs. the LINQ equivalent?

1 - When your business logic requires examining different data rows or large amount of data in general before it makes a decision or before it calculates a result, stored procedures have the advantage of doing this processing on the database server itself and could take a binary decision or perform the calculation on the server without passing any business data to the client. This results in good performance indeed. Let' say you have a complex business rule that would need examining 3 tables before you perform an insert. If you want your middle tear to do that, you have to bring the data via a query or more to the middle tear, execute the C# code (for example) and then continue with the insert or raise an error. When you implement the same logic on the server, you don't have to pass any data to the client (except the result).

2 - Stored procedures are also used in triggers and that is something you can't use LINQ for.